# Dropbox 400 Error in JavaScript Datastore API Request

Tags: dropbox-api

I'm attempting to post a large number of records (2000-ish) to Dropbox via the Datastore JS API. I'm getting this error:

`POST https://api12.dropbox.com/1/datastores/put_delta 400 (Bad Request)`

...and it references: `api12.dropbox.com/1/datastores/put_delta:1`

That's not a lot of info to use when debugging, but I'm guess it's because I'm over the size limit.

Any ideas how I can fix this or at least debug it further?

**Update**

I used the XHR inspector in Chrome to get this response:

```
{"error": 
  {
  "size_limit": "Error: put_delta of delta (size 4138335) exceeds size limit 2097152 bytes",
  "object_type": "delta", 
  "limit": 2097152, 
  "size": 4138335
 }
}
```

Comment: Is there anything in the body of the response? I believe it should contain more useful information about the error.

Comment: I looked again and found the response JSON (see above). If I don't know what the size of the `POST` will be in my app. Is there a way for me to break up the request into chunks? Is there a way to "sync" periodically like there is in the iOS SDK to keep the request size down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JS SDK, there's an implicit "sync" every time your code yields control back to the browser. So if you write a for loop entering a lot of data, that will all go into a single delta. You can break things up by writing in smaller chunks. For example, something like this (untested, sorry if there's an off-by-one error or the like):

```
var LIMIT = 100; // how many things to write in a single delta

function writeThings(arrayOfThings) {

    // write up to LIMIT things
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfThings.length && i < LIMIT; i++) {
        writeSingleThing(arrayOfThings[i]);
    }

    if (i < arrayOfThings.length) {
        // more to write

        window.setTimeout(function () {
            // after a tick, continue from where we left off
            writeThings(arrayOfThings.slice(i));
        }, 1);
    } else {
        // done writing
    }

}
```

Comment: This is interesting and helpful, thanks. Is the `if/else` statement supposed to be inside the `for` loop so it can reference `i`?

Comment: No, the `if/else` is where it's supposed to be. `i` should still be in scope. Why, are you seeing an error?

Comment: You're right, it still is in scope (JavaScript is weird). :) I found my real issue. The `setTimeout` function needs the function to be the first parameter, and the timeout interval to be the second parameter. This is working great for me now. I can upload large datasets without hitting the delta limit. Thank you!

Comment: Cool! I updated the answer to match the right use for `window.setTimeout`.